# Pure JS json parsing with many objects from local JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, parsing

I am confused about how to use jsons. 
Until now I always had to use 'in-code' arrays which I was comfortable iterating over and such.

Now I have to parse json file and get data out of it but my output to DOM element is:

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

and so on and so forth.

Would anyone kindly explain how am I supposed to get things to work?

My code for the moment:

```
<h1 id="json" onclick="json();">click</h1>
<script>
function json(){
  $.getJSON("./assets/songs.json", function(json) {
    console.log(json);
    document.getElementById('json').innerHTML = json.songs;
  });
}
```

Link to .json file I used: [click](http://davidpots.com/jakeworry/017%20JSON%20Grouping,%20part%203/data.json)

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(json));` to make it readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say this is behaving correctly. `json.songs` is an array of JavaScript objects which you are outputting to the DOM. If you want to display what's inside `json.songs` you'd have to go through the objects and use the actual values.

Maybe this snippet can illustrate the difference:

```js
const json = JSON.parse('{"songs":[{"title":"1904","artist":"The Tallest Man on Earth","year":"2012","web_url":"http://www.songnotes.cc/songs/78-the-tallest-man-on-earth-1904","img_url":"http://fireflygrove.com/songnotes/images/artists/TheTallestManOnEarth.jpg"},{"title":"#40","artist":"Dave Matthews","year":"1999","web_url":"http://www.songnotes.cc/songs/119-dave-matthews-40","img_url":"http://fireflygrove.com/songnotes/images/artists/DaveMatthews.jpg"}]}');

// Put the objects inside the <p>
document.querySelector(".objects").textContent = json.songs
// Put a string of the objects in the <p>
document.querySelector(".objectString").textContent = JSON.stringify(json.songs);
// Use the actual value
document.querySelector(".value").textContent = json.songs[0].artist;
```

```html
<p class="objects"></p>
<p class="objectString"></p>
<p class="value"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you! 
I am in the middle, because @McRist gave me an answer too, but yours is much more explainatory, so I think your will be marked as 'answer'. 

Now it's much clearer!

Comment: One more thing, when parsing my local file, not an array that's defined already in the code, how should I go about it? 
Use Jquery to get it, or... ?

Comment: @ŁukaszFormela yes you can use Jquery getJSON method.

Comment: Use whatever tool you see fit for what you're trying to achieve. Using jQuery in your case is fine. If you want to go the vanilla JS way look at [using `fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Answer (score 2):

```js
function json(){
var url = "http://davidpots.com/jakeworry/017%20JSON%20Grouping,%20part%203/data.json";

$.getJSON(url, function (json) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(json.songs));
       document.getElementById('json').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json.songs);

});

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<h1 id="json" onClick="json()">click</h1>
</body>
```

Use `JSON.stringify(json)` to get the JSON in a string format.

Comment: console.log(Uncaught TypeError: json is not a function); 
That does not work, should I have jquery or something I am missing, maybe there's a library for that kind of stuff that helps managing all the data?

Comment: `JSON` have you used this is uppercase?

Comment: I copy-pasted it.

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle link?

Comment: Thank you for your help! 
Your demo is working as expected but the answer above is more explainatory. 
Although thanks for sparing your time for me!

Answer (score 1):

For `JSON` conversion there are two functions:

- `JSON.parse()`       >> accepts `JSON` as argument and returns javascript Object
- `JSON.stringify()`   >> accepts JS object as argument and returns a `JSON` string

For example:

```js
let Object = {
  prop1: 1,
  prop2: 2
}

let JSONstring = JSON.stringify(Object);

console.log(JSONstring);
console.log(typeof JSONstring);

let objectAgain = JSON.parse(JSONstring);

console.log(objectAgain); // bugs in SO try in JSbin

console.log(typeof objectAgain);
```

Comment: That's very nice! I wish it was so clear on W3C or MDN. 
I don't know why, but their examples are either confusing or I am too new to this stuff.

Comment: Yes they are not very welcoming for beginners sometimes, just code a lot and your general knowledge increases. Then you know where to find relevant info ;)